# Using exclusive or in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as below

Table foobar

```
|foo|bar|
---------
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
```

I need to be able to do something similar to this

```
select * from foobar
where foo = 1 or bar = 1
```

Which would return the below

```
|foo|bar|
---------
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
```

Meaning that what is returned is exclusively 1 for the value. Is there such a thing as XOR in mysql that functions like this?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/187088/4/0

Comment: And the documentation I found by googling seemed to exclude a concise and above all 'clear' explanation as to whether the Xor implemented in MySQL was indeed 'exclusive' and not some strange (to me) bitwise operation

Comment: Yeah the MySql documentation is a VERY harsh read. I always check the stack first. I'm not sure how asking how an operator ACTUALLY works would result in opinionated answers or spam. This question should not be closed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, XOR. MySQL XOR operator checks two operands (or expressions) and returns TRUE if one or the other but not both is TRUE.

```
select * from foobar
where foo = 1 XOR bar = 1
```

The actual mathematical representation of a XOR equation "`A XOR B`" is "`(A AND (NOT B)) OR ((NOT A) AND B)`".

Comment: only few know XOR this is great help.

Comment: A cleaner mathematical notation of XOR is (A + B) % 2. In the literal example of either foo or bar being 0 or 1, you could write WHERE MOD(foo + bar, 2) = 1

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
select * from test where foo = 1 XOR bar = 1;
```

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/079cc/4

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that SQL does not offer an `XOR` by default. It is great that MySQL does because it's such a common feature. That being said, there is an easy way to "implement" and `XOR` when you have two booleans:

```
... WHERE (foo = 1) = (bar = 0)
```

This gives you the following:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| foo | bar |  =  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  0  |  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  0  |  1  |
|  0  |  1  |  1  |
|  1  |  1  |  0  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

To invert the results of the `=` column, use the opposite operator `<>` as follow:

```
... WHERE (foo = 1) <> (bar = 0)
```

Now you have an `XNOR` operator:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| foo | bar |  <> |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  0  |  0  |  1  |
|  1  |  0  |  0  |
|  0  |  1  |  0  |
|  1  |  1  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

You can also tweak the values, as in:

```
... WHERE (foo = 1) = (bar = 1)
```

So in case you are using a more pure SQL database such as [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-logical.html) which does not offer the Boolean XOR (as of 2019), this is an easy solution for you, much easier than the full:

```
(A AND (NOT B)) OR ((NOT A) AND B)
```

where you have to repeat `A` and `B` and that can end up being very costly in terms a filtering your results out, which is probably why it was decided not to include an `XOR` operator in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A clean mathematical notation of XOR is

```
(A + B) % 2
```

In the literal example of either foo or bar being 0 or 1, you could write

```
WHERE MOD(foo + bar, 2) = 1
```