# Mysql where = 'something' for search

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause

I need to write a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='somthing' ELSE WHERE user_name LIKE 'something%' ORDER BY user_name;
```

But I'm not sure how to write it.

the table is as follows:

```
id | user_name | frequency
```

The first record is

```
4 | fred | 1
```

so when searching for user_name = 'fred' if there are exact matches, show the most frequent record (highest frequency value) else if there are no exact matches show results like 'fred'

I have copied an example. the link is http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1802754&seqNum=3

Comment: `WHERE user_name LIKE 'something%'`? Since "something" also matches that? Anyway a basic SQL tutorial might help.

Comment: So i want to check if it equals that first but if not then do a like?

Comment: Like I said, [A basic SQL tutorial might help.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Comment: use normal OR. Else has no sense, SQL is not sequential language but declarative

Comment: I am assuming that you don't want the partial matches in case there is exact match. You may not be able to do this in a single query, you may have to write a stored procedure/fuction and then call it.

Comment: I cant find one that has a if else condition on a where clause?

Comment: So you want it to match something **OR** start with something else? (That was a hint)

Comment: yeah im trying to limit the amount of querys i have.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. I think you are looking for the Exclusive or.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using exclusive or in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181379/using-exclusive-or-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id INT,
    user_name VARCHAR(255),
    frequency INT
);

INSERT INTO users
VALUES
(4,'fred',1),
(5,'fred',2),
(6,'frederick',1),
(7,'freddie',1),
(8,'freddie',2),
(9,'john',1);

(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    users
    WHERE   user_name = 'fred'
    ORDER BY Frequency DESC
    LIMIT   1
)

UNION

(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    users
    WHERE   user_name LIKE '%fred%' AND
            NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT  *
                            FROM    users
                            WHERE   user_name = 'fred'
                            ORDER BY Frequency
                            LIMIT   1
                        )
)
```

Comment: I tried that but its finds both and i only want 1 or the other.

Comment: That is the nature of an OR clause, it finds 1 OR the other... do you need an AND?

Comment: So its for a search bar but i have a frequency count each name and order by sum of frequency if it finds where equals and where like it counts to many and shows the wrong order.

Comment: Where is the frequency count stored? You need to add your users table schema and data to your question....

Comment: id  |  user_name | frequency                                                                                        | 4   |     fred         |      1

Comment: so if there are two freds you want the one with the highest frequency to appear first?

Comment: yes and it does but need to add like so till the word equals 1 or more of the user names show what its like.

Comment: So if i search for 'Fred' it should show the most frequent Fred and anything that contains Fred such as Frederick?

Comment: so if user_name = 'fred' show results that contain most frequent fred else if user_name != 'fred' show results  like 'fred'