# why xor keyword not supported in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I using xor keyword in my sql it shows **keyword notfound.**
instead xor I am using **AND and OR**

Why it cannot directly supports?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Over flow. There are many different SQL versions, tied to the type of database server which you are using. Can you please tag what you are using with an appropriate version number.

Comment: The general reason "why does $language lack $feature" is [explained here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/)

Comment: Heh, I thought MySql had a [XOR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor)? F.e. see [this old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181379/using-exclusive-or-in-mysql).  So what version of MySql are you using that is missing the XOR?

Comment: @Caleth Thanks, that's a interesting article. Basically it boils down to the "once added it's a PITA to deprecate/remove, so choose wisely before adding a new feature".  And there's that thing about language design that adding to much core features to a language might give more expressiveness and flexibilty to coders. But because the same things can be done in different ways that makes mainting old code harder in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `XOR` is not part of the standard SQL syntax, by its definition:

```
a XOR b = (a AND NOT b) OR (NOT a AND b)
```

you can use it if you need it anywhere in a sql statement, like:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (a AND NOT b) OR (NOT a AND b)
```

Answer (score 3):

with MySQL 5.5+, XOR is officially supported.

[Reference 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor)
[Reference 2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/logical-operators.html)

Answer (score 2):

`XOR` is not part of the SQL standard.  It isn't now and never has been.  The reason is probably because the logic is not obvious to "business" users.

You can express it pretty easily:

```
where (x or y) and not (x and y)
```

Comment: instead of using 1 AND,1 OR  and 1 NOT gates. if we have 1 XOR gate it is very simple to use

Comment: @RajaSethupathiV . . . SQL is very far removed from the hardware.  Unfortunately, such optimizations would have little impact on query performance, which is dominating by the cost of accessing data.

Comment: you can write your own function for XOR